# Amazon EC2 .htaccess and 500 Error

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have an `Amazon EC2 (amzn-ami-pv-2013.09.0.x86_64-ebs (ami-149f7863))` on which I installed `Apache`, `PHP` and `MySQL`.

All works fine until I try to activate `.htaccess`.

I change `AllOverride All` in `http.conf` and restart the Apache service.

When I add the `.htaccess` file I receive a `500 Internal Server Error` even if the htaccess is void.

mod_rewrite.so module is loaded

If I delete the htaccess all works fine.

What I'm doing wrong?

**--EDITED--**

This is the .htaccess content

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But even if I left the htaccess file  whitout content it returns a 500 error.

The virtualhost definition is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.com
    ServerName mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**--EDITED-2-**

I'm sorry but I sorted out this issue only creating the .htaccess file from command line.
Now it works. Thank you really for helping me.

**--END-EDITING--**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your Apache error log say? Your site loads without the `.htaccess` in place, correct?

In my experience, when a 500 error is connected to `.htaccess` it could be something as simple as the `.htaccess` file itself getting munged on the file system.  I would recommend deleting the actual file and creating a new `.htaccess`. If that still shows a 500 error, then go through the `.htaccess` line by line commenting out each line and reload the page. Chances are there is something odd in at least one line and this will show it.

**EDIT:** I Looked closer at your `.htaccess` content since you added it & think I spotted the issue. Change it to read like so:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It seems like your formatting of the RewriteCond would choke.  Also, I adjusted it to the way I would do it which reads in human form:

> If this request is *not* to **www.mywebsite.com** *then* redirect it to
>   **www.mywebsite.com**.

This way you are clearly grabbing anything and everything that is **not** `www.mywebsite.com` and sending them to the proper domain.

Also, in your Apache config I would recommend a `ServerAlias` to account for `www.mywebsite.com`.  It seems like you are using `NameVirtualHost` so having the main server name be `www.mywebsite.com` with an alias being `mywebsite.com` makes the most sense.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I sorted out this issue only creating the .htaccess file from command line. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Happy it worked out. And like I said in my answer, it makes sense since sometimes `.htaccess` files can get munged in some text editors. One off character, and BOOM the site is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question as such; as you suggest, the `.htaccess` file itself shouldn't cause your server to return errors.  That means its probably what you have written into that file, or perhaps the combination with the apache settings.

I suggest you share the `VirtualHost` definition and the content of `.htaccess` tat causes the 500 error.

I also suggest you examine the apache logs, adjusting the config if necessary to obtain verbose enough logs to understand your issue.

At first glance, I'd guess a malformed <kbd>ReWrite</kbd> rule, as that's quite easy to do.

Comment: Added some details

Comment: I sorted out this issue only creating the .htaccess file from command line. Thank you for helping me.